# How to optimize a querySelectorAll record?

Tags: javascript, selectors-api, queryselector

I have a js code below. The question is - is it possible to combine this lines in one?

```
if (n === 6) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.dice#one .d_dot')[0].classList.remove('invisible');
    document.querySelectorAll('.dice#one .d_dot')[2].classList.remove('invisible');
    document.querySelectorAll('.dice#one .d_dot')[3].classList.remove('invisible');
    document.querySelectorAll('.dice#one .d_dot')[5].classList.remove('invisible');
    document.querySelectorAll('.dice#one .d_dot')[6].classList.remove('invisible');
    document.querySelectorAll('.dice#one .d_dot')[8].classList.remove('invisible');
  }
```

For example like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.dice#one .d_dot')[0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8].classList.remove('invisible');
```

(it doesn't work actually).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a loop.

```
var dice = document.querySelectorAll('.dice#one .d_dot');
[0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8].forEach(index => dice[index].classList.remove('invisible'));
```

Comment: It works! Cool!! Thank you so much @Barmar!
That's only for ES6 because of using '=>'? Right?

Comment: Correct. You can easily change it to `function(index)` if you need older compatibility.

Comment: Got it! It's very useful to know! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

`.querySelectorAll()` returns a node list (collection) of elements. A node list doesn't have a `classList`, the elements within it do, so you must do that to each element. However, there is an easier way, which is to loop through the collection and act upon each element within it:

```
let nums = [0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8];
document.querySelectorAll('.dice#one .d_dot').forEach(function(item, index){
  if(nums.indexOf(index) > -1 ){
    item.classList.remove('invisible'); 
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Looks it makes sense!